# PHP Imap Auth over other session

Tags: php, imap

I have an application with an auth layer already built and functioning.  I wish to add a small imap client within this application, but not sure how to handle the imap auth.  I have always built auth systems to salt/hash the password then to destroy any traces of the plain text password immediately... so, I've never had an experience handling a password that I need to maintain.

I would like the user to be able to login to imap from within the application (or upon the initial login) and have that login maintained while they use other features of the applications.

Any tips would be great ... thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the IMAP protocol requires you to know the password (the shared secret) to be able to authenticate with it.  When you login to IMAP you either use this directly, or use something like CRAM-MD5.

However, depending on the server, you can generally maintain IMAP connections indefinitely, by issuing a NOOP at least every 30 minutes.  However, any network issues will require you to log in again.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  So essentially I need to keep a plain text password stored in a session variable if I wish to keep it "logged in" ?  Can you provide more info on the NOOP for me?

Comment: NOOP is essentially just an IMAP command that says you don't want to do anything (no operation), but tells the server you're still there, and it can send any updates it has.  But, yes, unfortunately, you do need to store the password somewhere.

Comment: Thanks.  Any suggestions on how to store the password securely?  Like I mentioned, the thought has never even crossed my mind until now.  How does a package like RoundCube handle it?

Comment: I don't actually know PHP at all (but I try to help with the IMAP questions).  There's probably no way to store the password totally securely, but you can always use encryption to at least make it difficult for an attacker to get the password, unless they also have the decryption key.

Comment: For example, if you want to store the password in a cookie, you could use public key cryptography to store the password, and hopefully only you have the private key to descrypt it.

Answer (score 4):

For information, I checked out roundcube code and then...

Roundcube simply [encrypt the password and stores it](https://github.com/roundcube/roundcubemail/blob/master/program/include/rcmail.php#L580) in session:

```
$_SESSION['user_id']      = $user->ID;
$_SESSION['username']     = $user->data['username'];
$_SESSION['storage_host'] = $host;
$_SESSION['storage_port'] = $port;
$_SESSION['storage_ssl']  = $ssl;
$_SESSION['password']     = $this->encrypt($pass);
$_SESSION['login_time']   = time();
```

`$this->encrypt($pass)` refers to [`rcube::encrypt`](https://github.com/roundcube/roundcubemail/blob/master/program/lib/Roundcube/rcube.php#L777) which uses MCrypt to apply a 3DES encryption

Then it uses the symetric [`rcube::decrypt`](https://github.com/roundcube/roundcubemail/blob/master/program/lib/Roundcube/rcube.php#L829) method [when needed](https://github.com/roundcube/roundcubemail/blob/62350ba021d479e459cbbf7957841fbb440b9846/program/include/rcmail.php#L1956):

```
$host = $_SESSION['storage_host'];
$user = $_SESSION['username'];
$port = $_SESSION['storage_port'];
$ssl  = $_SESSION['storage_ssl'];
$pass = $this->decrypt($_SESSION['password']);
```

By the way, the encrypt method seems to make use of a secret salt (called "crypto_key" here).